# Code snippet not working after recent update to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, parameters, gravity

Hi all I am a bit stumped it seems after the latest update to wordpress this function has stopped working. Any ideas would be gratefully received . . .

First snippet gets the parameter "we" and should then auto fill the form field id #input_2_4 after making some calculations.

```
`<script>
$.urlParam = function (name) {
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                  .exec(window.location.href);
return results[1] || 0;
}
var we = parseInt( $.urlParam('we') );
$('#input_2_4').val( '£' + (we * 0.1450).toFixed(2));
</script>`
```

Everything seems present in the url string including &we=1685 value but field #input_3_4 is now blank.

[Link](https://scrapmycarcolchester.co.uk/stage-two/?EngineCode=D4EA7306231&Gearbox=&FuelType=DIESEL&Model=TUCSON+CRTD+CDX&Make=HYUNDAI&Year=2008&pc=Chris&we=1685&nfirst=Chris&cemail=notmyemail%40spanners.com&cmobile=12345678906&creg=test08tzs%C2%A0&cpcode=zz10+5lp)

Comment: Console log is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'urlParam' of undefined` so that's where I'd start. I'd also consider the normal issues with $ vs jQuery in WordPress jQuery interactions.

Comment: Thanks Tom, will look into jQuery conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it like below to remove any [$ issues](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/). Console.log should let you know if the issue is in getting the URL parameters. You may need to look at [enqueueing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) the script as well to make sure it's getting loaded in the proper order.

```
jQuery.urlParam = function (name) {
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                  .exec(window.location.href);
  console.log(window.location.href)
  console.log(results[1] || 0);
return results[1] || 0;
}
var we = parseInt( jQuery.urlParam('we') );
jQuery('#input_2_4').val( '£' + (we * 0.1450).toFixed(2));
```